# Run Delphi XE4 applications on Windows 2000 SP4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I have a tiny percentage (less than 1%) of my customers using Windows 2000 - is there anyway to get a Delphi XE4 application to run on Windows 2000 - accordingly to FAQ XE4 apps won't run on anything less than WinXP - but I am wondering if that restriction is hard-fixed or due to some specific API that will not work (or require unofficial updates to Win2K or similar)

Comment: So long as you don't use an API that is not present on W2K then you should be fine. You'll want to do some testing, so get yourself a W2K machine.

Comment: From personal experience - stock VCL XE2 applications worked on w2k. But as soon as DevExpress components are used - it requires GDI+ API libraries which Microsoft does not officially distribute to w2k customers

Comment: I'm the kind of person who hates the way M$ somehow manages to make every new release more bloated, yet still reduce functionality. So I loathe "up"grading. Yet I still reckon you're probably doing your customers a disservice by trying to support Win2K. Microsoft has officially discontinued support for WinXP, never mind Win2k. You don't even get security updates anymore.

Comment: @CraigYoung they still released Cry Virus update for xp/2003. But w2k is dead. Sad, it was so much better than XP...

Comment: I *think* I will have to ditch official support for Win2K completely / make it on customers own responsibility. Bu if anyone knows exactly what in XE4 made apps no work on Win2K I could possibly try make it still work.

Comment: Are you saying that mere creating empty VCL application in XE 4 - one simple form with no buttons nor other controls - would not run on w2k ?

If so, then take RTL/VCL sources of XE2 and XE4 and check the differences

Comment: You are wasting everyone's time by contemplating this without testing your program on a W2K machine. Why are you even commenting here, and posting more. Install W2K, test your program. Workaround any missing APIs if you feel it is worthwhile.

Comment: @Tom The point David is making is that you are the one who has your software. You are the only one who has full access to the source code and all its dependencies. You're the only one in a position to test and find out what does/does not work with Win2k. Asking us to come up with a list of all the various features (perhaps including 3rd party components) that don't work is a bit like asking for a list of stars not in Orion's Belt.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I was hoping someone knew from experience what problems there were in delphi XE4 with Win2K. (i.e. there can easily be multiple things to avoid - and some could even conceivably depend on other things installed in win2k installation / or possibly "patched" by downloading specific official/unofficial updates) -- I will take your advice and test on Win2k - unfortunately I lost my VMware machines so that is why I gave up on that and decided to throw up a question. That said, to actually test this would requirement a few Win2K installations (@Arioch'The yes - from docs it is so)

Comment: @Tom no it is not so, there is a difference: they do not warrant that it will be working, however it is not the same as if they did warrant it would not be working. See? There is white area (certainly works, we claim it), black area (certainly fails, we claim it), and gray area (who knows? random guess, no any claims). They moved the xe2 apps into gray area, but not into black area. Compare: there was such a project as KOL-MCK, which totally replaced both stock RTL and VCL. I even managed to make 2KB sized DLLs in Delphi 5. It was not supported by Borland but was not prohibited either.